# Object has no attribute _meta in python Cement App

Tags: python-2.7, command-line-interface

I am new to python and cement app,

I am just going through the documentation given in cement app and I am facing the following issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Amith/python/learning/inter.py", line 80, in <module>
    app.handler.register(MyHandler)
  File "/Users/Amith/python/learning/connectors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/handler.py", line 195, in register
    if not hasattr(obj._meta, 'label') or not obj._meta.label:
AttributeError: 'MyHandler' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I didnt find much help from documentation and verified few other wesites as well.

Please find my code below

```
from cement.core.foundation import CementApp
from cement.core.interface import Interface, Attribute
from cement.core import interface
from cement.core.handler import CementBaseHandler

def my_validator(klass, obj):
    members = [
        '_setup',
        'do_something',
        'my_var',
        ]
    interface.validate(MyInterface, obj, members)

class MyInterface(Interface):
    class IMeta:
        label = 'myinterface'
        validator = my_validator
    # Must be provided by the implementation
    Meta = Attribute('Handler Meta-data')
    my_var = Attribute('A variable of epic proportions.')

    def _setup(app_obj):
        """ The setup function """

    def do_something():
        """        This function does something.  """

class MyHandler(CementBaseHandler):
    class Meta:
        interface = MyInterface
        label = 'my_handler'
        description = 'This handler implements MyInterface'
        config_defaults = dict(
            foo='bar'
            )

    my_var = 'This is my var'

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = None

    def _setup(self, app_obj):
        self.app = app_obj

    def do_something(self):
        print "Doing work!"


class MyApp(CementApp):
    class Meta:
        label = 'myapp'
        define_handlers = [MyInterface]
        handlers = [MyHandler]

app = CementApp('myapp')
# define interfaces after app is created
app.setup()
print app.config.keys('myapp')
app.config.set('myapp', 'debug', True)
print app.config.keys('myapp')
app.handler.define(MyInterface)
app.handler.register(MyHandler)
app.run()
```

Any help will be much appriciated

Comment: Reference from http://builtoncement.com/2.10/dev/interfaces_and_handlers.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `MyHandler` does not properly sub-class `CementBaseHandler`.  Any methods need to be sub-classed with `super()`... for example:

```
class MyHandler(CementBaseHandler):
    class Meta:
        interface = MyInterface
        label = 'my_handler'
        description = 'This handler implements MyInterface'
        config_defaults = dict(
            foo='bar'
        )
    my_var = 'This is my var'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        # add your code here (if necessary)

    def _setup(self, app_obj):
        super(MyHandler, self)._setup(app_obj)

        # add your code here if necessary

    def do_something(self):
        print "Doing work!"
```

Notice the modifications to `MyHandler.__init__()` and `MyHandler._setup()` using `super()`...  this fixed the issue for me.

I apologize for the inconvenience in the documentation, and thank you for pointing it out with a proper/working/reproducable example.  I've added an issue to the project in Github to have it fixed in the next release.

- https://github.com/datafolklabs/cement/issues/423